# how to add rows to mysql database table and display it in a listbox in vb.net?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, listbox

I have the following controls:

- **textbox1 -** this is where i type a message.
- **listbox1 -** this is where i display the messages.
- **button1 -** this is what posts my messages to the server.
- **StatusStrip1.Title1 -** this is where the current user's title will go. (i.e: Administrator, manager... etc.)

I have a table on a MYSQL database called "messages" and a column called "message". When i type something into textbox1 and click button1 i want to add a row to "messages" under the column "message" with the title and message as its value.(separated by a hyphen, dash, or other small delimiter)Then reload listbox1's contents to show the new message.

so i want the final message to be something like:

> Administrator - Hello World!

I currently have the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sqlpost As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO messages(message) VALUES(?name - ?message)"";", con)
    sqlpost.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", Title2.Text)
    sqlpost.Parameters.AddWithValue("?message", TextBox1.Text)
    Try
        con.Close()
        con.Open()

        ' Sending message.
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("You forgot to type a message!")
        Else
            sqlpost.ExecuteNonQuery()

            ' Reloading messages.

            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            reader = sqlmessages.ExecuteReader()
            While (reader.Read)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(reader.Item("message"))
                ListBox1.Items.Add("")

            End While
            reader.Close()
            con.Close()
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            Label4.Text = "Message Sent!"
            Timer2.Start()
        End If

    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error sending message to server: " & myerror.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I had it working before, but when i made changes to it, it came up with various sql statement syntax errors... (stuff like invalid truncated value of "Administrator", or invalid DOUBLE value "hello") and now it won't even display any messages currently in the "messages" table...)

If anyone could tell me what i'm doing wrong, or a more efficient way of doing this then i would greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I see that looks incorrect is that you are using "?" for you parameter names in the query.  The default character to use for parameter names is to start them with "@".  Although I think there's a connection string option to use "?" as that is what was used in the older versions of the MySQL connector, but the current default is "@".  Also, there seems to be some problems with your command in general.  You have:

```
Dim sqlpost As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO messages(message) VALUES(?name - ?message)"";", con)
```

it should probably be something more like

```
Dim sqlpost As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO messages(message) VALUES(@message);", con)
```

I fixed up the query a bit, and replaced the ? with @.  You you can do the concatenation of name and message (as you cleared up in the comment) in VB, with some code such as this:

```
sqlpost.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", Title2.Text & " - " & Title2.Text)
```

I also see that you are calling

```
sqlmessages.ExecuteReader()
```

but I don't see where this is being initialized.

Comment: interesting, although my intention was to make the final message a combination of the persons title (represented by the name parameter) and the message they typed (represented by the message parameter) and separate them with a "-" character. so if the title was "admin" and the message was "hello world" i want the final message that is displayed to be "admin - hello world"

Comment: @Kibbee - MySql connector don't use @ syntax to assign parameter name.

Comment: See my recent changes for how to accomplish this.

Comment: @AVD Yes, the MySQL connector does use @ for parameter names, unless you are using the "OldSyntax" option in your connection string, as outlined here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html  Or you are using a really old version of the connector.  Reading further the OldSyntax paramter isn't even supported anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use single parameter.

```
Dim con as New MySqlConnection
con.ConnectionString="set_connection_string_here"
Dim sqlpost As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `messages` (`message`) VALUES (@name)",con)
sqlpost.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Title2.Text & " - " & TextBox1.Text)

If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("You forgot to type a message!")
Else
  con.Open()
  sqlpost.ExecuteNonQuery()
  con.Close()

  ListBox1.Items.Clear()
  sqlmessages.CommandText="select * from `messages`"
  sqlmessages.Connection=con
  reader = sqlmessages.ExecuteReader()
  While (reader.Read)
          ListBox1.Items.Add(reader.Item("message"))
  End While
  reader.Close()
  con.Close()
End If
```